# Track clicks on Elementor elements to Matomo

Tags: elementor, matomo

How to enable Matomo to track clicks on mailto links and tel links made with Elementor?

The Matomo script is added to Wordpress with the plugin "WP-Matomo Integration". The Matomo goals are listening to clicks to external websites with the pattern `mailto:(.*)` respectively `tel:(.*)`. Isn't the Matomo client script supposed to fetch the goals from the tracking server and listen to these events? Is there another way to trigger those events?

Answer (score 0):

I've created a script to search for elements with the class "matomogoal" and send the id of a goal to Matomo. It will push the goal id from the attribute `matomogoalid` to matomo, which you can get from your Matomo instance under Goals -> Manage Goals.

```js
function trackClickGoal() {
    var goalId = this.getAttribute("matomogoal");
    _paq.push(['trackGoal', goalId]);
}

if (typeof _paq != "undefined") {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("matomogoal");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].addEventListener('click', trackClickGoal, false);
    }
} else { console.error('matomo client script is is not initialized'); }
```

```html
<!-- HTML is supposed to look similar to this -->
<div class="matomogoal" matomogoal="goalid">
  <a href="mailto:nospam@nospam.com"></a>
</div>
```

You can set those attributes by editing the link in Elementor. In the left Elementor panel click on "Advanced and set the "CSS Classes" field to `matomogoal`:

[image]

Then click on "Attributes" and set the value of "Custom Attributes" to `matomogoal|goalid` (while using the goal's ID you want to track with this click):

[image]

This also works with multiple goals on one page.